# How to add the values of two rows into one row in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

```
'A','Peterson','2012-02-01','Cairo','10000'
'A','Peterson','2012-02-01','Cairo','5000'
'C','Baker','2012-04-01','Cairo','20000'
```

Say I have a table with these values (varchar(1), varchar(255), date, varchar(50), decimal)

And if the first two columns match, as they do in my example, then i should be outputted a table with two rows and the sum of the last column, as the follow:

```
'A','Peterson','2012-02-01','Cairo','15000'
'C','Baker','2012-04-01','Cairo','20000'
```

Where the last cell of the first row is the sum of the previous two rows that had that person's name. Thank you in advance!

I'm trying different syntax, but none of it is working.

Comment: This is basic `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`, which should be explained in most SQL tutorials.

Comment: Please show what you tried that didn't work, we're not going to do it for you.

Comment: Presumably you mean if the first 4 columns match. Search for "sql aggregates" in your search engine of choice, then come back and ask if you cannot get your aggregation to work as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the feedback, i have a better idea of what i need to find.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple aggregation and group_by example.

If, with this input :

```
+------+-----------+------------+--------+-------+
| Type |   Name    |    Date    |  City  | Value |
+------+-----------+------------+--------+-------+
| 'A'  | 'Peterson' | 2012-02-01 | 'Cairo'| 10000 |
| 'A'  | 'Peterson' | 2012-02-01 | 'Cairo'| 5000  |
| 'C'  | 'Baker'    | 2012-04-01 | 'Cairo'| 20000 |
+------+-----------+------------+--------+-------+
```

You want this output:

```
+------+-----------+------------+--------+-------+
| Type |   Name    |    Date    |  City  | Value |
+------+-----------+------------+--------+-------+
| 'A'  | 'Peterson' | 2012-02-01 | 'Cairo'| 15000 |
| 'C'  | 'Baker'    | 2012-04-01 | 'Cairo'| 20000 |
+------+-----------+------------+--------+-------+
```

You should use following query :

```
SELECT Type, Name, Date, City, SUM(Value) AS Value
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Type, Name, Date, City;
```